# Error getting user through Get-ADUser in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I'm having trouble with my script. Everytime I try it, I get this error message:

> Get-ADUser cannot find an object with identity

But the user does exist. 
Here is how im getting  all users from a specific group in my case it's "All-users":

```
[array]$u = Get-ADGroupMember $userset
```

After that getting users one by one to change password and send them email:

```
$u[$a] = Get-ADUser $u[$a] -Properties PasswordExpired, Enabled, PasswordNeverExpires, Mobile
```

**[code in gist.](https://gist.github.com/pwnz22/846a9113c8c7b3ebb9ebd06738639966)**

Error screen (but it's in russian):
[error screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ZUQI.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have changed this line:

```
[array]$u = Get-ADGroupMember $userset
```

with this:

```
[array]$u = Get-ADGroup $userset | Get-ADGroupMember -recursive | Get-ADUser -properties
```

And it worked as i need with no errors.